# Method until in class FluentWait<T> cannot be applied to given types

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, gradle, ui-automation

I am getting the following error while compiling selenium automation application using java and gradle version 3.4.

Error:

```
  method until in class FluentWait<T> cannot be applied to given types;
        return getWebDriverWait().until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(GOTO_ICON));
                                 ^
  required: Function<? super WebDriver,V>
  found: ExpectedCondition<WebElement>
  reason: cannot infer type-variable(s) V
    (argument mismatch; ExpectedCondition<WebElement> cannot be converted to Function<? super WebDriver,V>)
  where V,T are type-variables:
    V extends Object declared in method <V>until(Function<? super T,V>)
    T extends Object declared in class FluentWait
```

Build.gradle

```
   compile 'io.appium:java-client:3.1.0'
   compile 'com.applitools:eyes-selenium-java-jersey1x:2.29'

   compile group: 'org.seleniumhq.selenium', name: 'selenium-java', version: '2.46.0'
   compile 'org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-firefox-driver:2.52.0'
   compile 'org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-ie-driver:2.52.0'
```

Source code:

```
By GOTO_ICON = By.id("GoTo");
String windowContentLoaded = "//*[@id=\"windowContentLoaded\"]";

public WebElement getGoToHeader() {
    waitForPageToBeLoaded();
    return getWebDriverWait().until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(GOTO_ICON));
}

public void waitForPageToBeLoaded() {
    sleepSeconds(3);
    getWebDriverEx().waitForInvisibleElement(By.xpath(windowContentLoaded));
    return;
}
```

Comment: Assuming that you are trying to compile some sort of working open source, my guess is: your Java version is wrong. Either you should be using 1.8 but use 1.7 ; or vice versa.

Comment: No Luck. Before I used java 1.8. Now switched to 1.7 and ran into numerous issues.

Comment: what is your locator for  GOTO_ICON ?

Comment: I'm not sure that I follow, at some point this code was working and now it's not? Based on the code that you've provided I guess that you're trying to invoke .until() directly from webdriver, however you should pass webdriver as an argument to fluentwait constructor.

Comment: @kushalツ GOTO_ICON = By.id("GoTo");

Comment: Sorry I meant which <> tag it belongs to, is it an <a> or <img> tag?

Comment: @Mikhail Yes the code was working before and it's not working.

Comment: @kushalツ It's <button> tag under <div>

Comment: @Inaccessible you are trying to return outcome of the wait from a method, what is the return type of method in which you're trying to return?

Comment: as per this documentation: https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/FluentWait.html#until-java.util.function.Function-  Your method has return type set to WebElement but if element is not found within the time then it doesn't return web element, hence the error.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139207/discussion-between-inaccessible-and-kushal).

Comment: Chat is Not accessible to me at this time.

Comment: If you don't try to return this particular statement; then you won't see the error, probably.

Comment: The error mentioned in documentation should be raised during runtime. But I am getting compilation error. Also the error that I get doesn't relate to timeout.

Comment: The error says "method until in class FluentWait<T> cannot be applied to given types" and it doesn't relate to timeout.

Comment: in documentation you can see that if timeout happens then .until returns false or null

Comment: @Inaccessible did you try removing it from return statement?

Answer (score 10):

Not sure what would be the reason for the error in **Selenium 2.46.0**, however I've exactly the same error when switching from version **3.x** to version **4.x**.

It might not help the OP solve the problem, however I'm posting a solution for people coming here when searching for the same exception.

In the recent version of Selenium framework the `getWebDriverWait().until()` interface had changed a bit:

- Old versions

[image]

- New version

[image]

Now it accepts functional interface, with one argument (`WebDriver`) and return value depending on the `WebDriverWait` implementation, which in most cases is `ExpectedConditions`.

Try changing your code to:

```
public WebElement getGoToHeader() {
    waitForPageToBeLoaded();
    return getWebDriverWait().until(
        webDriver -> ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(GOTO_ICON).apply(webDriver)
    );
}
```

Comment: This was incredibly helpful. I wish I could upvote more than once.